# How to show the tooltip on d3 force directed layout node?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tooltip, data-visualization

I have built a  sample d3 visualisation with the hierarchy data, which works very well.I need to display the data binded to that icon/node when the user move mouse across the node. I have done that too, which works well.

I need to display the data according to the node on the tooltip. i do not want to bind an html element for the same.

Here is my code

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="chart"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
 node = vis.selectAll(".node");
        node = node.data(force.nodes());
        node.exit().remove();
        node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .on("click", click).on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible") 
                 tooltip.text
                 ;})
.on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top",
    (d3.event.pageY - 130)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX - 130 )+"px");})
.on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

[APPLICATION ON FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/qnykLx4g/3/)

Comment: are you saying you want to display the text on the node as tooltip on hover?

Comment: yes, not the text, the actual node value

Comment: Still not very sure i tried this...http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/75hd6gf1/ here on tooltip I show the node's value...Is this your requirement.

Comment: @Cyril Yes thank you, do you know how can i display it with a style. say name and the size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add class to tooltip do:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "my-tooltip")//add the tooltip class
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden");
    tooltip.append("div")
        .attr("id", "tt-name")
        .text("simple");
    tooltip.append("div")
        .attr("id", "tt-size")
        .text("simple");
```

To add value and size on mouse hover do:

```
tooltip.select("#tt-name").text(d.name)
tooltip.select("#tt-size").text(d.size)
```

Updated code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/75hd6gf1/1/):

Comment: I really tried this previously, but dint work for me, anywayThanks cyril . it was really helpful.